# Allow searching in multiple columns with multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

Here is my scenario: I have a search which searches multiple columns

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->_table WHERE r_title LIKE ?
   OR r_level LIKE ?
   OR r_section LIKE ?
   OR r_excerpt LIKE ?
   ORDER BY r_id DESC"
```

This works good, but for example the title could be `"Squash"` and the section could be `"Soup"` so if a user enters `"squash soup"` it doesn't return any results.

Does this make sense? How can I get it to deliver a more relevant, merged response?

The section would technically be called `"Soups"not "Soup",` I still want it to return "Squash Soup" if the section is really `soups,` just ignore the `"s"`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [MySQL's search functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MATCH(r_title, r_level, r_section, r_excerpt)
    AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY r_id DESC
```

[Boolean search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html), by default, looks for any word in the search phrase, so no pre-processing is necessary there. You'll need to make sure your tables have [appropriate indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-indexes.html#idm139720662429584) on them however:

```
ALTER TABLE table
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (r_title),
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (r_level),
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (r_section),
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (r_excerpt);
```